# Two different definitions of solid subspaces of a Riesz space

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lattice-orders, vector-lattices

In D.H. Fremlin, *Topological Riesz Spaces and Measure Theory*, [14C], a subset $F$ of a Riesz space $E$ is defined as **solid** if

> $x \in F$ whenever there is an $y \in F$ such that $|x| \le |y|$.

In G. Letta, *Argomenti scelti di Teoria della Misura*, Chap. VII, Def. (2.3), a linear subspace $F$ of a Riesz space $E$ is defined as **solid** if

> for every couple $(x,y)$ of elements of $E$, the following implication holds:
> $$0 \le x \le y \in F \Rightarrow x \in F. $$

It is quite obvious that Fremlin’s definition implies Letta’s, for Fremlin’s condition coincides with Letta’s when $x$ and $y$ are positive.

**Questions.**

1. Is Letta’s condition equivalent to Fremlin’s, at least when the set is $F$ is a linear subspace of $E$?
2. Is it true in general that Letta’s condition implies Fremlin’s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letta's condition does not necessarily imply Fremlins's condition even if $F$ is a linear subspace of $E$.
Let $E = \mathbb R^2$ with $(x_1,x_2) \le (y_1, y_2) \Leftrightarrow (x_1 \le y_1 \text{ and } x_2 \le y_2 )$.  Let $F = \{(t,-t) : t \in \mathbb R\}$.  See that Letta's condition is satisfied (because if $0 \le y \in F$, then $y = 0$).  But Fremlin's condition fails, because $|(1,0)| \le |(1,-1)|$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have only a little question: in point 1, we know that $y \in F$. How does Letta’s condition imply that also $|x| \in F$? Rather than this detail, I understand perfectly your answer, particularly on Question 2. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know why you are asking if $|x| \in F$.  But note that $|x| = x^+ + x^-$.

Comment: I was asking about $y$ actually. If it doesn’t lie in $F$ the argument doesn’t work, does it?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: I changed my answer.  Tell me what you think?

Comment: It looks perfect! I understand the initial issue with $|y|$, which was the same I had. I think Letta’s and Fremlin’s coincide only when the set $F$ is a linear subspace of $E$ which is also a Riesz space with the induced order given by $E$. In that case, $F$ is stable under $x \mapsto |x|$ which is what makes them equivalent. Thank you for helping me with this, @StephenMontgomery-Smith.